# jQuery animate malfunction external CSS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, external

I am trying to use jQuery to animate the full-page (html) background by clicking the menu buttons. I created a small try-out in W3school TryIt Editor, and this worked. However, when I want to use it on my own site, it doesn't work (and the jQuery stops working in general - the alert doesn't show anymore as well).Is there anyone that can help me with this?

This is the error Firebug gives me:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]   

$('.html').animate(left:'0px')

script.js?mcplzp (line 32, col 35)
```

This is my actual JS code:

```
$('.html').animate(left:'0px'

    (function ($, Drupal) {
        $("<link/>", {
       rel: "stylesheet",
       type: "text/css",
       href: "../css/pages.css"
    }).appendTo("head");

    if (jQuery) {  
        alert('jQuery is loaded!');  
        };

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.menu-704').click(function() 
            {
                $('.html').animate(left:'0px'
            });
    });

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.menu-797').click(function() 
            {
                $('.html').animate(left:'=+1250px'
            });
    });

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.menu-359').click(function() 
            {
                $('.html').animate(left:'=+1250px'
            });
    });

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.menu-796').click(function() 
            {
                $('.html').animate(left:'=+1250px'
            });
    });


    })(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: What is the error displayed in the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try the following, which I've tested and it seems to work.

1) Your animate method should be called like this:

```
$('.html').animate({left:'+=1250px'})
```

Not like this:

```
$('.html').animate(left:'=+1250px')
```

The CSS properties and values you're passing (in this case 'left' positioning) should be wrapped in bracket {} notation.

2) Try replacing:

```
=+
```

With:

```
+=
```

3)  if you're targeting the **html** element, you may not want to use a class of 'html' on the element itself.  Since you'll only have one **html** element per document, try doing this instead:

```
$('html').click(etc...
```

4) If you implement the changes outlined in 1 - 3, this should fix your issue.  However, once resolved you may want to clean-up the code a bit which will certainly help in debugging issues next time 'round.  You only need one $(document).ready(function(){}); within which you'll set all of your $('foo').click() event listener stuff.

**So instead of this:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.menu-797').click(function() 
    {
        $('.html').animate({left:'+=1250px'});
    });
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.menu-359').click(function() 
    {
        $('.html').animate({left:'+=1250px'});
    });
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.menu-796').click(function() 
    {
        $('.html').animate({left:'+=1250px'});
    });
});
```

**Simplify to this:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.menu-797,.menu-359,.menu-796').click(function() 
    {
        $('.html').animate({left:'+=1250px'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped! The usage of this code was to move the background of the complete site (in this case, the class HTML background). I need to figure out which class/id I have to actually call, but it does work now!

Comment: Glad it helped David - have a great one!

Comment: I now have the code like you suggested it, but replaced '.html' with 'body'. The thing is; When I click on a menu-button now, the whole body of the site (but NOT the background-image of the body) moves to the right. I want this the other way around; The actual body of the site has to stay fixed, but the background-image of the body has to move to the right. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, that's what will happen since you're instructing it to move the 'html' element (and thus everything within - ie: the whole page).  If all you need is shifting background image try adding a image to the page <img src="backgroundimage.jpg" id="background-image" />, which you'll want to position 'absolutely' or 'fixed', as well as properly set the z-index (so it sits behind all other content on the page) and animate this image.

Comment: I actually fixed it different, which also worked great! This is what I did:
$('body').animate({backgroundPosition:'+=1175px 0px'});

Comment: Awesome.  Glad you got it working David.  Btw, if my answer was helpful - feel free to vote it up ;)